# NSTableViewRowAction - Slide back after clicking

Tags: cocoa, swift4, nstableview, xcode10, macos-mojave

I added a slide feature to my table view using `tableView(_:rowActionsForRow:edge:) -> [NSTableViewRowAction]`, but I found that when I click the leading button, it works fine, but it just doesn't slide back.

This is the code for my row action:

```
extension ViewController: NSTableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, rowActionsForRow row: Int, edge: NSTableView.RowActionEdge) -> [NSTableViewRowAction] {
        // some other codes
        switch edge {
        case .trailing:
            // some other codes
        case .leading:
            let revealInFinderAction = NSTableViewRowAction(style: .regular, title: "Reveal in Finder") { (action, row) in
                self.revealInFinder(row: row)
            }
            revealInFinderAction.backgroundColor = .systemOrange
            return [revealInFinderAction]
        }
    }
}
```

**For example,** one of my buttons does the "Reveal in Finder" job (`revealInFinderAction`), after clicking the button, it revealed the file in the Finder, but it didn't slide back.

I found that Apple's Mail app can perfectly handle this, after clicking the Mark as read/unread button after sliding one of the cells, it did its job and automatically slide back. I just want to find a way to make the same thing happen.

I've done research on how to achieve this, but I cannot find a solution for it, is there anyone can help me please? I'm using Xcode 10 with Swift 4 on macOS 10.14.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting `tableView.rowActionsVisible = false`, like this:

```
case .leading:
        let revealInFinderAction = NSTableViewRowAction(style: .regular, title: "Reveal in Finder") { (action, row) in
            self.revealInFinder(row: row)
            tableView.rowActionsVisible = false
        }
        revealInFinderAction.backgroundColor = .systemOrange
        return [revealInFinderAction]
```